# output for a value index in pandas, returns a boolean array

Tags: python, pandas

when searching for a unique value index in a pandas dataframe, it works perfectly. but when that value is not unique, the output seems to be an array of booleans:

load the file in:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test_file.csv')
print(df.head(10))
```

and lets say this is the file i am dealing with:

```
   test
0    10
1    20
2    10
3    20
4    20
5    20
6    10
7    10
8    10
9    30
```

now when i try to get the index of a value that is not unique in the column:

```
output_index = df.set_index('test').index.get_loc(10)
print(output_index)
```

output:

```
[ True False  True False False False  True  True  True False]
```

but the same code works just fine when its done for a unique value:

```
output_index = df.set_index('test').index.get_loc(30)
print(output_index)
```

output:

```
9
```

so what is the correct way to get the index(es) of a value that has occured more than once in a dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
output_index = df[df['test'] == 10].index
```

if you need a list:

```
output_index = df[df['test'] == 10].index.to_list()
```

Answer (score 1):

**[`df.index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.index.html)** returns the row labels for a particular value.

If the value is `repeated` in the dataframe, it will return all the indexes, like below:

```
df.index[df['test'].eq(10)].tolist()
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 2, 6, 7, 8]
```

If the value is `unique`, it will return:

```
df.index[df['test'].eq(30)].tolist()
```

**Output:**

```
[9]
```